# Why is map.values().stream() much slower than Array.stream(array)

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

Creating two constructs for University second semester computer science to count words in a text.
One implementation uses an Array with Word-Objects which save the word as string and its frequency as int.
The other uses as HashMap with the Word as key and the frequency as value.
Now their is a function "totalWords" that should return the sum of all frequency.

In the HashMap variant:

```
return _map.values().stream().reduce(0, (a, b) -> a + b);
```

In the array variant:

```
return Arrays.stream(_words)
            .map((word) -> word != null ? word.count() : 0)
            .reduce(0, (a, b) -> a + b);
```

My problem is: in a JUnit test with a very short test text the Array variant does need approximately 0.001s and the map variant needs 0.040s and I do not understand why the map does need so much more time.
Has anybody an explanation and maybe a better solution?

Comment: The main reason is that your benchmark is flawed. Writing such a micro-benchmark is extremely difficult in Java. The second reason is that iterating over the entries of a HashMap can't be as fast as iterating over an array.

Comment: A side note concerning the "better solution": Iterating over the elements of a `LinkedHashMap` tends to be noticably faster than for a plain `HashMap`. Not as fast as for an array, though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the reason is that iterating a `HashMap` can be much slower than an `Array`, the reason is `locality`. The computation bottleneck of modern processor is dominated by memory access, and that's why `cache` is used. `Array` stores data in a contiguous chunk of memory, which means when you swap that chunk of memory into cache, it is more likely that you are using everything in the cache, or you get `cache hits`, so cache likes contiguous memory of data. On the other hand, each element of `HashMap` is stored in different place in the memory, so when you traverse the `HashMap`, you get a lot of cache `misses`, you end up with swapping data in and out of cache all the time, which dramatically slows down you program.

Although the actual implementation of `HashMap` is in an optimized way such that the data in the memory is clustered together, but even in this case, (@Radiodef)since `HashMap` uses some sort of `linked list`, each element of `HashMap` contains extra pointers, so a `HashMap` consumes more memory than an `Array`, more memory means more `cache misses` and more `page faults`, so `HashMap` in general is slower than `Array`.

Answer (score 0):

A HashMap is a data structure which has (basically) an array of linked lists:

```
0: [ a ] -> [ b ] -> [ c ]
1: [   ]
2: [   ]
3: [ d ] -> [ e ]
4: [   ]
5: [ f ]
6: [   ]
7: [   ]
```

The linked lists are places where keys had the same hash code (called a "collision").

So the data structure has "holes" in it, and also it's more fragmented than an array because a HashMap has an object for every entry. Iterating a HashMap will generate more loads from memory than iterating an array.

I also agree with JB Nizet your benchmark is probably flawed. A good benchmark would probably still show that an array performed better but not as stark a difference.